# Django: Template isn't loading app_tags file. Unable to use custom filter: "Invalid Filter"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have the following folder structure:

```
myProject
        |
       myapp
           |
          templatetags
                     | __init__.py
                     | app_tags.py
```

The app_tags.py file:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=False)
@stringfilter
def upper2(value):
    """Converts a string into all uppercase."""
    return value.upper()
```

The test.html template:

```
{% load app_tags % }

<div>Test Word: {{ test_word }}</div>
<div>Test Word: {{ test_word|upper2 }}</div>
```

If I use the `{{ test_word|upper2 }}` I get an `Invalid filter: 'upper2'` error.

[image]

If I don't try to use the `upper2` filter, the `{% load app_tags % }` doesn't appear to be loading.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And... there was a white space in `{% load app_tags % }`

Once I changed the loading tag to `{% load app_tags %}`, it worked great!